# FFMPEG Opengl video rendering

Tags: c++, opengl, video

I'm searching any way to render with ffmpeg, an opengl texture that contains the video frame.

Actually, I am not good with ffmpeg... Is there any library/documentation or something?
How can I render a video with ffmpeg to opengl?

Thanks

Comment: Have you looked at gStreamer libraries at all?  I use them at work for video streaming/pipeline work.  Take some getting the hang of, but they're quite comprehensive (use FFMPEG in places too).

Answer (score 2):

Example implementation with basic demos: http://code.google.com/p/openmedialibrary (opengl/openal frontend to an ffmpeg backend)

Comment: On SE sites, it's preferred for answers to include relevant content, not just link to it.  If the link goes dead, the answer becomes non-useful.

Comment: I'm prettttty sure the relevant content in this case is rather big.

Comment: However, I'd like to point that the linked project is GPL, so its usefulness is limited.